# Cannot connect to database in MVC once SQL Server installed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am running through this MVC tutorial for visual studio - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-model

Great tutorial by the way. But when I made this movie app originally everything worked. But now i have this error when connecting to the database.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146233087 Message=An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

I have attached the stacktrace below.

Here is the connection strings I used in the Web.config file (the bottom one is for the database I am trying to connect to).

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20140922085615.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20140922085615;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I think I know the cause of the problem I just don't know how to solve it. This all went south when I installed the Microsoft SQL Server 2014. When I ran this same program under virtual box on my mac it worked. So the problem is not with the code and my mac does not have SQL Server installed.

If anyone could help I would greatly apprecaite it. Bare in mind I am kind of new to programming and so I would appreciate quite explicit and easy to follow instructions/advice.

Some people mentioned in the comments that they created an SQL database and that worked but I don't know what or how to do this in visual studio nor the connection string I need. If anyone can give me good instructions on this that would be great!

```
Source=EntityFramework
 StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MvcMovie.Controllers.MoviesController.Index() in c:\Users\basse_000\OneDrive\Documents\MVC\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 20
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
   HResult=-2146233087
   Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
   Source=EntityFramework
   StackTrace:
        at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
        at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        HResult=-2146232060
        Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
        Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
        ErrorCode=-2146232060
        Class=20
        LineNumber=0
        Number=2
        Server=""
        State=0
        StackTrace:
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
             at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<UsingConnection>b__2d()
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
             at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
             at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
        InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
             HResult=-2147467259
             Message=The system cannot find the file specified
             ErrorCode=-2147467259
             NativeErrorCode=2
             InnerException:
```

Comment: Arent you missing `Database Name` in your connection string?

Comment: Well this was copied from the tutorial and it works on windows run on my mac?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running both in visual studio?  Or is the mac visual studio and the pc a published version?  You are getting the error because it can find one of these files

```
|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20140922085615.mdf
|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf
```

in an MVC site |DataDirectory| should resolve to the App_Data folder in the root of your site, so the first thing you should do is check to see if those files are there.  If they are your sql server may have reconfigured the locations somehow - I'm not sure.  You can use

```
var actualDataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
```

to find out where it's looking and override that with something like this

```
var path = Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(path, path);
```